# Get sorted list of indices, for a list of dictionaries sorted by a given key

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with multiple keys and I would like to get multiple lists each with the indices of the dictionaries, sorted by a particular key.

For example, I have the following list

```
a = [{"name": "Zoe", "age": 13}, {"name": "Adam", "age": 31}]
```

I know that I can do the following

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(a, key=itemgetter("name"))
```

to get the following

```
[{'name': 'Adam', 'age': 31}, {'name': 'Zoe', 'age': 13}]
```

but I really want to be able to get two lists with the indices instead:

```
[1, 0] # order of the elements in `a` as sorted by name
[0, 1] # order of the elements in `a` as sorted by age
```

My real dictionary has many more key-value pairs and it's more efficient for me to return `a` and the additional lists with indices as sorted by different keys rather than multiple sorted lists of `a`.

Comment: So exactly what are you expecting as output? a list of lists, where each sublist is a sorted `a` list?

Comment: `sorted(a, key=itemgetter("name"))` this part should raise a `NameError`. Are they exactly same  code you've tried?

Comment: @marmeladze: I think we can assume that there is a `from operator import itemgetter` line.

Comment: @marmeladze no. but Martjin has fixed it the way it should

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks. i was typing out on the fly...

Comment: @AnandSKumar multiple lists... in my example, two lists, one `[1, 0]` and one `[0, 1]`. and of course i will name those two lists properly so I know what keys they are sorting

Comment: @minovsky: so you want to produce *integers* in the output list?

Comment: You just wanted the index position as the output?

Comment: correct... so I want `a_sorted_by_name = __SOME_CODE_HERE` and `print a_sorted_by_name` would print `[1, 0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can produce a sorted list of *indices* by producing a `range()`, and then adjusting the sort key to translate an index to a specific value from a dictionary from the `a` list:

```
sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: a[i]['name'])
sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: a[i]['age'])
```

If you know the keys up front, just loop and produce multiple lists; you could perhaps create a dictionary keyed by each sorting key:

```
{key: sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: a[i][key]) for key in ('name', 'age')}
```

The above dictionary comprehension then gives you access to each sorted list based on the sort key alone:

```
>>> a = [{'name': "Zoe", 'age': 13}, {'name': "Adam", 'age': 31}]
>>> {key: sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda i: a[i][key]) for key in ('name', 'age')}
{'age': [0, 1], 'name': [1, 0]}
```

Comment: for my example, i just want to have two lists... one `[1, 0]` and another one `[0, 1]`...

Comment: trying to be clearer... I want `a_sorted_by_name = __SOME_CODE_HERE` and `print a_sorted_by_name` would print `[1, 0]`

Comment: That's a nice example of indirect sorting Martijn! And I guess it's just as efficient as any `sort()` using a key function, since (I assume) they're all indirect sorts under the hood.

Comment: @PM2Ring: yes, both are straightforward O(1) lookups. My version doesn't require duplicating indices into the dictionaries though. :-P

Comment: I'm so used to doing the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) that I sometimes forget to use a simpler, more elegant approach. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: this is still a Schwartzian transform, of course. But since the desired output was to produce indices, not the dictionaries themselves, I started with generating indices to sort.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is to add an index field to the dicts in your list.

```
from operator import itemgetter

a = [{'name':"Zoe", 'age':13}, {'name':"Adam", 'age':31}]

for i, d in enumerate(a): 
    d['index'] = i

def get_indices(seq):
    return[d['index'] for d in seq]

by_name = sorted(a, key=itemgetter("name"))
print by_name
print get_indices(by_name)

by_age = sorted(a, key=itemgetter("age"))
print by_age
print get_indices(by_age)
```

**output**

```
[{'index': 1, 'age': 31, 'name': 'Adam'}, {'index': 0, 'age': 13, 'name': 'Zoe'}]
[1, 0]
[{'index': 0, 'age': 13, 'name': 'Zoe'}, {'index': 1, 'age': 31, 'name': 'Adam'}]
[0, 1]
```

Of course, you don't need to keep the sorted lists of dicts, you could just do

```
by_name = get_indices(sorted(a, key=itemgetter("name")))
```